# Linked List, Creation of struct

Tags: c++, linked-list, structure

How are we able to create a pointer of type node inside the struct node when the struct is not fully defined.

```
struct node
    {
        int data;
        node* next;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is because the standard says so.

The longer answer is that the size of a pointer (a pointer to data, anyway) is always the same and so the compiler knows what it is even though `node` is not yet fully defined.  It is therefore able to determine the layout of `node` without knowing what is coming next, and that's enough to keep it happy.

Contrast your code snippet with this:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node next;
};
```

Now the compiler is in trouble, because each `next` will contain another `node` which will contain another `next` and so on, ad-infinitum.  This code, therefore, will not compile.  But with a pointer, it's fine.

---

As per @GoswinvonBrederlow's comments, more formally `struct node` introduces `node` as an [incomplete type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type), even if you immediately follow it by `{ ... };`, and within the declaration of `node`, `node` is considered declared but incomplete.

Following on from that, diving into the [standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.compound-3) tells us that:

> ... Pointers to incomplete types are allowed ...

which is what makes your example work.  As I say, it's how the language is designed.  C is much the same.

Comment: You should also mention that it's the same with abstract types: `struct Foo; Foo *foo;` works just fine.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Not what the OP asked, but fair enough.

Comment: I think it's very much applies. `struct node { ... }` is equivalent to `struct node; struct node { ... };` if that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Not really, I'm not at all sure what you're trying to say here.  I mean, you're not wrong, but the OP wanted to know why he can use a pointer to an incomplete `struct` inside the declaration of that `struct`, so let's just stick to the point.

Comment: And the reason is that before you even open the `{}` the compiler already has the abstract type of the struct declared and you can use pointers of abstract types.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Don't you mean 'incomplete type'?

Comment: Yes, I do......

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow OK, added something. I'm glad we got there in the end.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask the compiler to allocate node* next you actually ask to allocate memory of size of a pointer, which is fixed size for all pointers types.

So the compiler don't need to know the size of struct node when you declare it.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, you need to know that the computer doesn't understand high-level software conceptualizations like structs.

In fact, when compiling your code to assembly, **no such thing as a structure is ever generated**. Instead, from the parsing/semantic analysis of the C compiler, a clearly structured code is generated, where your CPU will fulfill its purpose through the addressing of bits in the different transistors through routing tables.

```
typedef struct {
    int x; 
} entity_t;

int main(){
    entity_t entity; 
    entity.x = 34; 
}
```

**Assembly Code: Simply, a value assignment to a static memory location with a 4-bit weight occurs on the stack of the main function.**

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 34
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

These routing tables have 2 rule classification categories to have a data transmission format through the buses, these categories are: **The memory address** of a static/dynamic location of the RAM/CPU Cache and **the value stored in that memory address** (bits).

From this, Dennis Ritchie proposed the concept of subroutines **as abstraction layers to spare us** all the complexity involved in managing memory from assembler pointers.

Now, concepts as complex as recursion, in the first instance would be impossible to implement in computation because the definition tells us that a recursive function must call itself even if it is not completely defined.

Faced with this problem, C handles recursion from pointers, since pointers are entities with a memory address totally different from the address of the type or function to which you want to apply recursion. For this reason, for a recursive data structure like a linked list, it is only possible to have a link to another memory location of the same type through pointers.

**In short, recursion in this type of data structure is possible through pointers because the pointer itself is a completely different memory address than the containing type.**

Answer (score -2):

forward declarations

```
 struct node;
 struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
}
```

Comment: [That's not necessary](https://wandbox.org/permlink/47EeH5y9A09nml4H)